# type command for decimal?

Tags: python, types

I am a newbie to python. I am learning about `type` command.

Can anyone tell me why this is returning as `int` while it is a decimal number which is assigned?

```
>>> m=0b1011
>>> type(m)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: What do you think the value of the number you entered should be?

Comment: i entered a binary digit right . but y it is showing int type instead of binary

Comment: You entered a integer number, the fact that you typed its value in base 2 doesn't change this: it's still what we usually call 11 (eleven) in base 10.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "binary number" in Python. For much the same reason that `'foo'` and `"foo"` evaluate to the same value.

Comment: in this case all the variables will give the same output. iam i correct ?In the console, assign values to the following variables as mentioned and print type of each variable in separate lines.

x = 6
y = 12
m = 0b1011
n = 0xad4   @Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Numbers are created by numeric literals or as the result of built-in functions and operators. Unadorned integer literals (including hex, octal and **binary numbers**) yield integers.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex

Comment: In the console, assign values to the following variables as mentioned and print type of each variable in separate lines. x = 6 y = 12 m = 0b1011 n = 0xad4   . so in this case every output  will be int ?

Comment: @venky513 exactly. same for octal, e.g. ``var = 0o45``. All of them will be handled as integer. It's just the representation during the assignment that differs.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> m=0b1011
```

These are just 1s and 0s: they are not *inherently* a decimal or an integer.

It all depends on how you choose to interpret the 1s and 0s that give them their value. For exampple, `0b1011` can have the decimal value `11` if you choose to interpret it as regular binary, or the decimal value `-5` if you choose to interpret it as two's complement.